# How can I create a Windows system restore point that won't be overwritten by Windows in the future?

Tags: windows-8.1, backup, restore, system-restore

Since Windows regularly creates system restore points, it overwrites old ones when the allotted space for system restore is full. What I'm trying to do is make a system restore point of my PC's current state and make sure that it won't be overwritten by Windows.

I know that I could make a system image but I have ruled that option out because it will also overwrite my personal files (documents, music, etc.).

If this is not possible to do, does anyone know of another way to restore my system without affecting personal files? Besides manually copying system folders, that is.

Comment: you can use the system image as you already suggested and always put your personal files on another partition which will not be affected by image restoration

Comment: Only two options i could consider. 1. Increase the allotted space for System Restore under "System Protection" > Configure, where by to certain limit the space can be increased and you have much more restore points then the default. Else, 2. System Image backup is the other option provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, I've considered these options although I'd rather not choose them if there is a better alternative.

Comment: It's a bit hacky but you can try this: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/copy-system-restore-points-45595.html

Comment: overwriting your personal files shouldnt be an issue if you back them up regularly...

Comment: Part of the problem with system image is that even if I have a backup of my personal files, the old files and folders that I have deleted (but existed at the time of the system image) will exist again. I don't want to go through all the files a have already deleted and re-delete them.

Comment: I know the article is a bit outdated and Windows seems to have made the process even harder. You will simply have to dig deeper through the permissions, like 3 more pop-up windows deeper, to add your user account to the permissions list. At least that's what I had to do in my Windows 7.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I just tried that but I don't see any restore points. I followed the guide step by step and dug as deep as possible but there was nothing in the folders. The folder structure was "C:\System Volume Information\SystemRestore\FRStaging" but there's nothing in them.

Comment: @Jorge24 Do you intend to use these permanently-held restore points in a bare metal recovery scenario (e.g. your hard drive fails and you have to start from scratch)? Or are you assuming you'd use them only with your existing Windows installation?

Comment: @Twisty Bare metal recovery scenario. I just reinstalled Windows for the 3rd time this week (had a recurring issue) and I want to be able to restore all my current settings and software in case the issue comes back. As opposed to having to do set up everything again (install OS , install software, updating software, set desired settings, etc)

Comment: Windows (up to 7 at least) by default periodically reminds you to make full system backup, but that does not mean doing so fits your purpose. Twisty showed how to plan this out, once you have a plan test it - then you do not need to worry about much else but to keep to your plan. This should work with most consumer OS I believe. In your case bring up a Windows install with all hardware and software updates and image it. Then you can try risky things, and image the second time when they work and prove to be stable. Otherwise reset and start over again. For this purpose I use systemrescueCD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Windows 8 you can create a [Refresh Image with Recimg.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc.aspx) which does what you want with those 2 commands:

```
mkdir C:\RefreshImage

recimg -CreateImage C:\RefreshImage
```

You now have a "restore point" which never goes away and where you can restore to, but in opposite to the original Refresh command in Windows 8, you don't loose any desktop applications.

Comment: Nice. Can you move it off-line, that is burn it or archive it and use it later somehow? Move it to a different disk? How do you delete it if you need to free up some space? Is it included and appreciated by disk management software dealing with NTFS? Qs abound.

Comment: This is not a syspreped image, it can be only used on the current Windows/hardware.

Comment: I think I found a software that lets you manage these images created by recimg. Here is the [link](http://www.recimg.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Since you need to be able to perform a bare metal restore of your Windows installation, permanently saving restore points is a very bad idea.  Permanently saving a restore point is challenging enough, but restoring it to a foreign Windows installation is bound to introduce ghosts in the machine.

You're much better off making a complete system image. To deal with the fact it would contain old (previously deleted) user data, you could maintain separate backups of your user data and then a recovery scenario would look like this:

1. Restore complete system backup
2. Create a temporary admin account on the computer
3. Use the temporary admin account to delete your "old" user profile
4. Restore your separate user data backup

If your user data backup wouldn't restore your data if your user profile doesn't exist, an alternate restore scenario would be:

1. Restore complete system backup
2. Logon your user account and delete all data you know to be protected by your user data backup
3. Restore your user data backup

Comment: Thanks for the alternative method, do you know if full system images can be used on other PCs? or only on the PC for which it was created?

Comment: It's usually possible to restore a system image to different hardware, but if you're counting on being able to do so, the only correct way to know is to test your disaster recovery scenario. Typical issues include the disk layout being different on the target machine (it must be identical to the source), problems with storage drivers not being correct, etc. Testing is the only sure way to go.